# ST7789 LCD Driver Row Address Set Bug

Tags: microcontroller, lcd, tft

I'm using a 320x240 LCD with a ST7789 driver in 8 bit parallel mode. I'm just getting things set up and am trying to draw a small square in the middle of the screen to make sure everything is working properly but cannot manage to do that because of unexpected behavior when trying to set the starting and ending row address (RASET, 0x2B). The column address responds correctly to how I set it but not the row address. I've attached pictures with various X/Y start/end coordinates to describe this behavior. Hoping someone can spot what I'm missing because I am dumbfounded as to why this isn't working. Thanks for looking.

[Link](https://newhavendisplay.com/content/datasheets/ST7789V.pdf) to ST7789 datasheet.

[Link](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/seeed-technology-co.,-ltd/104990542/10244653?utm_adgroup=Seeed%20Technology%20Co.%2C%20LTD.&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Shopping_DK%2BSupplier_Tier%201%20-%20Block%202&utm_term=&utm_content=Seeed%20Technology%20Co.%2C%20LTD.&gclid=CjwKCAjwzNOaBhAcEiwAD7Tb6GvrILjzfYmZZ8CEaW4ThqKS2YNy5M-ZN48wYHMAgVG_FDu5M5inWhoCU4YQAvD_BwE) to screen I'm using.

Display data and row/column address set written at end of lcdInit().

```
/*Starting coordinates*/
#define X_START                     100
#define X_END                       200
#define Y_START                     0
#define Y_END                       200
#define TOTAL_PIXELS                ((X_END + 1) - X_START) * ((Y_END + 1) - Y_START)

void lcdInit()
{
    ioSetPinIO(&LCD_PORT, LCD_BACKLIGHT_PIN_bm | LCD_CS_bm | LCD_RD_bm
                | LCD_DC_bm | LCD_WR_bm | LCD_RESET_bm);                //All control pins as IO.
    ioSetPinOutput(&LCD_PORT, LCD_BACKLIGHT_PIN_bm | LCD_CS_bm | LCD_RD_bm
                | LCD_DC_bm | LCD_WR_bm | LCD_RESET_bm);                //All control pins as output.
    
    ioSetPinIO(&LCD_DATA_PORT_bm, LCD_DATA_PINS_bm);                    //Set all the data pins as IO.
    ioSetPinOutput(&LCD_DATA_PORT_bm, LCD_DATA_PINS_bm);                //Set all data pins as outputs.
    
    ioPinHigh(&LCD_PORT, LCD_CS_bm | LCD_RESET_bm | LCD_RD_bm);         //Start with chip select high.
    ioPinLow(&LCD_PORT, LCD_WR_bm);                                     //Start with the write signal low.

    
    delay_ms(100);

    /*HW Reset*/
    ioPinHigh(&LCD_PORT, LCD_RESET_bm);
    delay_ms(10);
    ioPinLow(&LCD_PORT, LCD_RESET_bm);
    delay_ms(10);
    ioPinHigh(&LCD_PORT, LCD_RESET_bm);
    delay_ms(200);

    /*SW Reset*/
    lcdBegin();
    lcdWriteAddr(0x01);
    lcdEnd();
    
    delay_ms(250);
    
    /*Read display ID*/
    lcdBegin();
    lcdReadAddr(0x04, 4);
    lcdEnd();
        
    /*Exit sleep mode*/
    lcdBegin();
    lcdWriteAddr(0x11);
    lcdEnd();
    
    /*Required after exiting sleep mode.*/
    delay_ms(250);          

    /*Select color mode RBG565*/
    lcdBegin();
    lcdWriteAddr(0x3A);
    lcdWriteData8bit(0x55);
    lcdEnd();
    
    /*MADCTL register pg 215, sets the orientation of the screen*/
    lcdBegin();
    lcdWriteAddr(0x36);
    lcdWriteData8bit(0);
    lcdEnd();
    
    /*Normal display mode as opposed to partial display mode*/
    lcdBegin();
    lcdWriteAddr(0x13);
    lcdEnd();
    
    /*Tearing effect off*/
    lcdBegin();
    lcdWriteAddr(0x34);
    lcdEnd();
    
    /*Display on*/
    lcdBegin();
    lcdWriteAddr(0x29);
    lcdEnd();
    
    delay_ms(120);
    
    /*Read status register*/
    lcdBegin();
    lcdReadAddr(0x09, 5);
    lcdEnd();

    delay_ms(1000); 
        
    /*Set range of screen from (0,0) to (239,319).*/
    lcdBegin();
    lcdWriteAddr(0x2A);         //X direction.
    lcdWriteData16bit(X_START);     //X Start.
    lcdWriteData16bit(X_END);       //X End.
    lcdEnd();
    
    delay_ms(1000);
    
    lcdBegin();
    lcdWriteAddr(0x2B);         //Y Direction
    lcdWriteData16bit(Y_START);     //Y Start.
    lcdWriteData16bit(Y_END);       //Y End.
    lcdEnd();   
    
    delay_ms(1000);
        
    /*Write display data to the screen*/
    lcdBegin();
    lcdWriteAddr(0x2C);
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < TOTAL_PIXELS; i++)
    {
        lcdWriteData16bit(0xf800);
    }
    lcdEnd();
}



void lcdWriteData16bit(uint16_t data)
{
    /*One pixel is 16 bits, can only send 8 bits at a time.*/
    union dataSplit
    {
        uint16_t data;
        struct bytes 
        {
            uint8_t msb;
            uint8_t lsb;
        }bytes;
    }dataUnion;
    
    dataUnion.data = data;
    
    ioPinHigh(&LCD_PORT, LCD_DC_bm);                                //DCX pin high for data.
    
    /*Write the msb to the bus*/
    ioPinHigh(&LCD_DATA_PORT_bm, 
                (uint32_t)dataUnion.bytes.msb & 0x000000FF);        //Cast and mask to not overwrite the rest of Port B.
    ioPinLow(&LCD_DATA_PORT_bm, 
                (~(uint32_t)dataUnion.bytes.msb) & 0x000000FF);     //Cast and mask to not overwrite the rest of Port B.
    ioPinHigh(&LCD_PORT, LCD_WR_bm);                                //Latch in the data.
    
    delay_us(100);                                                  //Wait for a bit.
    
    ioPinLow(&LCD_PORT, LCD_WR_bm);                                 //Release latch.
    
    delay_us(100);                                                  //Wait a bit.
    
    /*Write the lsb to the bus*/
    ioPinHigh(&LCD_DATA_PORT_bm, 
            (uint32_t)dataUnion.bytes.lsb & 0x000000FF);            //Cast and mask to not overwrite the rest of Port B.
    ioPinLow(&LCD_DATA_PORT_bm, 
            (~(uint32_t)dataUnion.bytes.lsb) & 0x000000FF);         //Cast and mask to not overwrite the rest of Port B.
    ioPinHigh(&LCD_PORT, LCD_WR_bm);                                //Latch in the data.    
    
    delay_us(100);                                                  //Wait for a bit.
    
    ioPinLow(&LCD_PORT, LCD_WR_bm);                                 //Release latch.

    delay_us(100);                                                  //Wait for a bit
}
```

[image: Starting coordinates (0,0). End coordinates (239,319)]
[image: Starting coords (100,0). End coord (239,319).]
[image: Starting coords (100,0). End coords (200,319).]
[image: Starting coords (100,100). End coords (200,319).]
[image: Starting coords (100,0). End coords (200,200).]
[image: Writing column address.]
[image: Writing row address.]

Comment: In most display parallel interface applications WR and RD are idle high and active low, where the receiver samples the data at the falling edge. Your code uses idle low, however the falling edge is at the correct position except initialization code.

Comment: @Jens Are you saying I should leave WR high after the last byte is written for every transaction so it's high when nothing is happening?

Comment: Yes, that is the typical way, similar to a write access to parallel memory chips. Ancient TTL chip current consumption was much higer at a low input level, so it is tradition to use active low signals there. Apply the data, WR low, WR high is the sequence. WR low and RD low at the same time is an illegal combination.

Comment: Table 11 of the ST7789 datasheet is quite clear about that.

Comment: Unfortunately, no change in behavior when leaving WR high.